# Exchange 2013 Outlook "Send to cache"

Tags: exchange, smtp, outlook-2010, exchange-2013

Having some trouble with users changing AD accounts but their primary SMTP address is moved to the new account.
Let me explain:
User Andersson1 gets a new AD accout because he changes department and now gets the AD account Andersson2. The old account was mailbox enabled with the address of Andersson@contoso.com and this address is now moved to the new account which has been mail enabled (the address on the old account is deleted).
But when people now type his name in the "Send To" field in Outlook and the cache auto completes it finds him correctly but the email is still trying to be sent to his old account.
Would it help to also migrate the x400 address?

Comment: I think the simplest solution here is to stop creating new AD accounts every time a user moves to another department. Unless your business organisation or your IT infrastructure is purposely being run as part of a social experiment in creating the least efficient way of doing things possible, there should be absolutely no need for this.

Comment: There are rules that requires this to be done.